Read a file of protobuf-messages using mutiny
Using Mutiny, I want to read Protobuf-Messages from a file. I want to collect these Messages in an io.smallrye.mutiny.Multi. The file itself can be quite large.
Each Protobuf-Message has a factory method .parseDelimitedFrom(InputStream). So in a nutshell, this code should be able to collect all messages of type ProtoMessage:
InputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("my/file"));
List<ProtoMessage> result = new ArrayList<>();
ProtoMessage message;
while ((message = ProtoMessage.parseDelimitedFrom(inputStream)) != null) {
  result.add(page);
}

But I fail to translate this learning into an async, non-blocking Mutiny shell.
@Inject
io.vertx.mutiny.core.Vertx vertx;

Multi<ProtoMessage> readProtoMessages() {
  final Path path = Path.of("my/file");
  Uni<AsyncFile> uni = vertx.fileSystem().open(path.toString(), new OpenOptions().setRead(true));
  return uni.onItem().transformToMulti(AsyncFile::toMulti).flatMap(this::toProtoMessage);
}

@SneakyThrows
private Multi<ProtoMessage> toProtoMessage(Buffer buffer) {
  List<ProtoMessage> result = new ArrayList<>();
  InputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(buffer.getBytes()));
  ProtoMessage message;
  while ((message = ProtoMessage.parseDelimitedFrom(inputStream)) != null) {
    result.add(message);
  }
  return Multi.createFrom().items(result.stream());
}

While I have a Unit-Test showing that I get my expected ProtoMessages from a test file using the code above, I feel this solution is not "correct". The .open() seems to write the entire file to Buffer, so it blocks?
What would be the preferred way of reading the file on an "on-element" basis? Can I pass the result directly to a Multi, instead of collecting them all in a list first?

The code below shows that the files is read into small chunks/buffer:
this.vertx.fileSystem().open(FILE, new OpenOptions().setRead(true))
      .onItem().transformToMulti(file -> file.toMulti())  <------ this line, breaks the file into buffer chunks
      .onItem().transformToUniAndMerge(buffer -> {
            System.out.println(buffer);
                    ...
       }); 

This prints out the file in chunks.
It should be non-blocking, however when it comes to performance and resource usage: I didn’t find it faster or better than the iterative approach.
And if you want to read the file line by line you need to do the following:
RecordParser.newDelimited("\n", vertx.fileSystem().open(FILE, new OpenOptions().setRead(true)).onItem().transformToMulti(AsyncFile::toMulti))
     .toMulti()
     .onItem().transformToUniAndMerge(line -> {
           // ...
     });

However, be cautious with this code, especially if your file is huge. Because it’s super slow.
